# Definir parágrafo com maior largura possível

Tags: css

Estou tentando encaixar perfeitamente um parágrafo `p` em um item de lista `li` para fazer um cabeçalho com menu de opções (igual ao do site [python.org/downloads](https://www.python.org/downloads), que estou recriando para praticar), sendo o texto de cada uma dessas opções centralizado vertical e horizontalmente.

O problema é que quando eu defino `width: 100%` para o parágrafo, ele simplesmente ignora essa instrução e fica com a menor largura possível, ou seja, a largura da palavra. Ao definir `width: 198px`, que é o tamanho do `li` no meu viewport, funciona absolutamente perfeito. Ele até regula o próprio tamanho ao diminuir a largura do browser. Só que eu quero adequar minha página a resoluções maiores, então esta não é uma opção. Segue o meu trecho em HTML:

```
<div id = interface>
    <header id = header_superior>
        <nav id = nav_superior>
            <ul>
                <li id = hs_python><p>Python</p></li>
                <li id = hs_psf><p>PSF</p></li>
                <li id = hs_docs><p>Docs</p></li>
                <li id = hs_pypi><p>PyPI</p></li>
                <li id = hs_jobs><p>Jobs</p></li>
                <li id = hs_community><p>Community</p></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </header>
</div>
```

E meu trecho em CSS (o resto eu não coloquei pra não ficar muito extenso, mas creio que esteja aqui mesmo o problema):

```
#header_superior ul {
    list-style: none;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0;
    font-size: 0;
}

#header_superior li {
    display: inline-block;
    color: #999;
    width: 16.4%;
    height: 47px;
    border-left: 1px solid #273643;
    border-right: 1px solid #1f3b47;
    font-size: 12pt;
}

#header_superior p {
    width: 198px;
    height: 47px;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Comment: Tendo um tempo da uma olhada neste exemplo: https://jsfiddle.net/yLhjok05/ pode te ajudar em algo. No Inspector algumas propriedades estão no :hover, :active ou outros. Clique com o botão direito sobre o elemento e vai em "force state", force o estado que desejar e as propriedades aparecerão.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

dica 1: abre o inspetor de html no site que você está copiando para ter acesso as definições do css

```css
#header_superior ul {
    list-style: none;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0;
    font-size: 0;
}

#header_superior li {
    display: inline-block;
    color: #999;
    width: 16%;
    height: 47px;
    border-left: 1px solid #273643;
    border-right: 1px solid #1f3b47;
    font-size: 12pt;
}
#header_superior li:hover{
    color: #000;
}

#header_superior p {
    width: 100%;
    height: 47px;
    line-height: 47px;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<div id = interface>
    <header id = header_superior>
        <nav id = nav_superior>
            <ul>
                <li id = hs_python><p>Python</p></li>
                <li id = hs_psf><p>PSF</p></li>
                <li id = hs_docs><p>Docs</p></li>
                <li id = hs_pypi><p>PyPI</p></li>
                <li id = hs_jobs><p>Jobs</p></li>
                <li id = hs_community><p>Community</p></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </header>
</div>
```

Comment: Muito obrigado! Deu certo, não sei por que estava dando errado antes, mas deu certo a sua solução. Sobre o inspetor, acho que só aparecem algumas das propriedades dos objetos, não encontrei quase nada lá.